# Not able to connect over network

Tags: internet, desktop

I have a desktop which is running Windows XP. For the last few days, the internet was working fine. Recently the internet stopped working.

For some days it worked for only 2 hours a day, then the internet stopped working completely. In the toolbar it is showing that the internet is connected and the speed is 100Mbps (indicates internet port is working).

When I connected the internet cable to my laptop it worked fine. Then I formatted my desktop with Windows 7 and configured TCP/IP configurations the same as i had done on my laptop.

I am still getting the same problem (shows the network but no internet access).

Why is the internet working for my laptop but not for my desktop?
How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: when you said 'i've configured TCP ports same as i done in my laptop, you mean you are doing custom configuration in your network card??

Comment: TCp ports means IP address, subnet mask, default gateway and preferred dns server properties of Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)

Comment: Make sure the "IPv4 address" for your laptop and desktop are not the same! E.g. Laptop could be 192.168.1.10 and the desktop could 192.168.1.11 - this is good. if they are the same numbers then you have an IP collision and may be causing the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Can you tell us what your LAN IP details are? Gateway IP (should be something sensible like 192.168.1.1). You should also have a subnet mask of something like 255.255.255.0 and then each laptop/.desktop could be something like 192.168.1.10 and .11 respectively..

Comment: @BigChris , My ip details are like you mentioned only and the subnet mask is as it is. And one more thing is I have not connected both my laptop and desktop to network at a time, so there is no chance of collision

Comment: Can you also tell us whether you have a router or is it just a modem? Many ISPs provide a combined modem/router. This should be configured to automate the addressing of your devices so you leave them at "automatic"...

Comment: if this guide posted down doesnt work with a SOHO router, that means you question is so unclear and we are misunderstanding all, review yourself, improve your post, provide us more useful information as screenies and we could help maybe....

Answer (score 0):

First at all if the interface shows is working with 100Mbps Full Duplex that doesnt mean you have internet. to have internet usually in home you should check the following things.

- An [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) provider conections(check with company if is any problem with the ISP)
- All ISP devices working and configured properly(check with company if is any problem with the devices)
- Usually the Home/Office devices works with a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)/[PAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Port_address_translation) and [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) to get [Network Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address) Translation to reach the [WAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network) and get a valid [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) configuration with Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol if not you should define a valid IP Segment and a Valid [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) Server to reach the Internet.

You can check in this way if your Network card is Working Properly to get DHCP as well.

In Control Panel, under Pick a Category, click Network and Internet Connections.

there select your NIC and Right Click Properties.

that should open a windows as this

[image]

There press Internet Protocol v4 (TCP/IPV4)
 and press property button. it will open this window:

[image]

To Work both options should be Automatically or you can define [GOOGLE DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

as Well.

Comment: I tested with specified google DNS IP's, But no use